# Macro in GCC works but in Solaris Compiler fails?

Tags: c++, macros, compiler-errors, solaris, exiv2

source: svn checkout svn://dev.exiv2.org/svn/trunk (Latest rev: 3020)

My platform: Fedora 17 64-bit

The following command works:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-library=stlport4 -    
DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/opt/oracle/solarisstudio12.3/bin/CC -        
DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/opt/oracle/solarisstudio12.3/bin/cc .
```

But after that when I do make, I get the error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target exiv2lib
[ 17%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/exiv2lib.dir/asfvideo.cpp.o
cd /home/Wani/GSoC/exiv2-trunk/trunk/src && /opt/oracle/solarisstudio12.3/bin/CC   -    
DEXV_BUILDING_LIB -DEXV_HAVE_DLL -DEXV_LOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -
DEXV_HAVE_STDINT_H -library=stlport4 -KPIC -I/home/Wani/GSoC/exiv2-trunk/trunk -
I/home/Wani/GSoC/exiv2-trunk/trunk/xmpsdk/include    -o 
CMakeFiles/exiv2lib.dir/asfvideo.cpp.o -c /home/Wani/GSoC/exiv2-
trunk/trunk/src/asfvideo.cpp
"/home/Wani/GSoC/exiv2-trunk/trunk/src/error.cpp", line 29: Error: Multiple declaration 
for rcsId.
1 Error(s) detected.
```

Content of error.cpp:

```
28 #include "rcsid_int.hpp"
29 EXIV2_RCSID("@(#) $Id: error.cpp 2681 2012-03-22 15:19:35Z ahuggel $")
```

Content of rcsid_int.hpp:

```
#ifndef RCSID_INT_HPP_
#define RCSID_INT_HPP_

#if !defined (EXIV2_RCSID)
#if defined(__clang__)
#define EXIV2_RCSID(id)

#elif defined(OS_SOLARIS)
#define EXIV2_RCSID(id) \
{ \
inline const char* getRcsId(const char*) { return id ; } \
const char* rcsId = getRcsId(rcsId); \
}

#else
#define EXIV2_RCSID(id) \
namespace { \
inline const char* getRcsId(const char*) { return id ; } \
const char* rcsId = getRcsId(rcsId); \
}
#endif

#endif 
#endif
```

If I compile the same program using GCC, it works without errors.

See the diff, as Rev 3019 works in GCC and Solaris Compiler: http://dev.exiv2.org/projects/exiv2/repository/revisions/3020/diff?rev=3020&type=sbs

How to ignore multiple declaration error in Solaris Compiler?

I've calculated the diff of the pre-processed output of the .cpp files in r3018 and r3019:

```
 2a3,6
 > #30 "/home/Wani/exiv2-trunk/trunk/src/asfvideo.cpp"
 > namespace { inline const char * getRcsId ( const char * ) { return "@(#) $Id$" ; }           
 const char * rcsId = getRcsId ( rcsId 
 > #30
 > ) ; }
```

Comment: Look at the preprocessed sourcecode, and you will see that you define a variable twice.

Comment: But then why does GCC not throw this error? How can I repair it? Please see the diff. The macro OS_SOLARIS is mandatory for Solaris OS

Comment: Apparently GCC fails to report this error. The C standard does not mandate that compilers catch all your errors; it only does so for a subset. The One Definition Rule (ODR) is not part of that subset.

Comment: Could you please explain how is the macro defined two times? Won't the if-else directives make sure that the macro is defined only once?

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani: compare the preprocessed source codes of both.

Comment: @PlasmaHH @MSalters If I append -E to the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, I get `CC: Warning: "-c" redefines goal from "preprocessed source (file)" to "object file".` How do I rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted a comment on this issue to exiv2.org's wiki and provided the patch
which worked past the problem.

The essential issue is that the Solaris Studio compilers do *not* allow multiline
macros in C++. The patch I provided elided this because it commented out the
entirety of the rcsId declaration.

As best I can determine, the correct declaration in rcsid_int.hpp is as follows:

```
#if defined(__clang__) || (defined(OS_SOLARIS) && defined(__SUNPRO_CC))
#define EXIV2_RCSID(id)
#else
#define EXIV2_RCSID(id) \
    namespace { \
        inline const char* getRcsId(const char*) { return id ; } \
        const char* rcsId = getRcsId(rcsId); \
    }
#endif
```

This results in the pre-processed source *not* containing an rcsId string.

Comment: Please have a look at this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16088950/gcc-compiles-fine-but-solaris-compiler-doesnt