# GCC Compiles fine but Solaris Compiler doesn't?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, solaris, exiv2

source: svn checkout svn://dev.exiv2.org/svn/trunk (rev: 3019)

My platform: Fedora 17 64-bit

The following command works:

```
./configure CXX=/opt/oracle/solarisstudio12.3/bin/CC \
     CC=/opt/oracle/solarisstudio12.3/bin/cc CXXFLAGS="-v -library=stlport4"
```

But when I do make, I get the error:

```
libtool: compile:  /opt/oracle/solarisstudio12.3/bin/CC -v -library=stlport4 -    
xldscope=hidden -I. -DEXV_LOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/share/locale\" -I../include -funsigned-
char -DNDEBUG=1 -DEXV_HAVE_STDINT_H=1 -c XML_Node.cpp >/dev/null 2>&1
CC: Warning: Option -funsigned-char passed to ld, if ld is invoked, ignored otherwise
/opt/oracle/solarisstudio12.3/prod/lib/amd64/crt1x.o: In function `_start':
fsr.s:(.text+0x3b): undefined reference to `main'
make[1]: *** [XML_Node.o] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/Wani/GSoC/exiv2-trunk/trunk/xmpsdk/src'
make: *** [xmpsdk] Error 2
[Wani@Linux trunk]$
```

Can anyone tell what is the exact problem here?

The same source when compiled with GCC gives no error and compiles successfully.

Comment: What is your `main` prototype? `int main()`, `int main(int, char**)` or even something else non-standard?

Comment: @syam: There is no main() method in XML_Node.cpp . GCC ignores this and compiles successfully. Is there any option that will make Solaris Compiler do that same?

Comment: @syam: Why is it necessary to have a main() method?

Comment: Well if you are building an executable, it must have an entry point (main) in one translation unit of your project, otherwise there is nothing to execute. Since you don't have a main in your project and GCC doesn't complain, I can only guess you are building a library (but on Solaris somehow the compiler thinks you are building an executable). If that is so, you may want to check your compilation options.

Comment: @syam: Where can I get those compilation options? You are right, I am building a library. How do I make the Solaris Compiler realize that?

Comment: I don't know the Solaris compiler so I can't help you with the options it needs. As to "*Where can I get those compilation options?*", it depends on the build system you use. For GNU/Linux this is often in the Makefile (or Makefile.am if you use automake).

Comment: I use Solaris - don't have access right now. The linux Makefile and Solaris Makefile are likely to be very similar.